# HTML Input File in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, webview

Can html input file be used in android webview? If not, what are the workarounds?

```
<input type="file" name="file />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebView by default doesn't open file chooser. However it is possible to make this work. WebChromeClient has hidden method openFileBrowser, which needs to be overridden to pop up a file chooser and then return the result to WebView

**But I would think that you could modify things such that an onClick event on the  would call into Java code that you inject via [addJavascriptInterface()][1], at which point you can bring up whatever sort of "file explorer" you want.**

http://m0s-programming.blogspot.in/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html

Comment: from the comment of the link, they got errors. But, I will try this. Thank you.